# Assinging constant value to one among different variables based on a condition

Tags: java, conditional-statements

Normally in ternary operation, LHSside is constant, RHS changes.

```
int marks;
String result = (Grade > marks) ? 'PASS' : 'FAIL';
```

But, what I want

```
int marks;
if(Grade > marks)
    passMark = marks;
else
    failedMark = marks;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can technically do:

```
marks = (Grade > marks) ? (passMark = marks) : (failedMark = marks);
```

Which will give you what you want, but the problem is `marks` is just being assigned the same value it already had because you cannot just have *no* variable assignment when using the ternary operator.

This is a bit confusing, so I don't know if I condone this.

[Java Docs Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) for conditional operator:

> It is a compile-time error for either the second or the third operand expression to be an invocation of a void method.

This is relevant because say you extract the `passMark = marks` to a method:

```
public static void passMarks(){
   passMark = marks;
}
```

And try to use it like:

```
(Grade > marks) ? passMarks() : failedMarks();
```

It would be a `void` method because you do not actually *need* to return anything, your logic is already complete.  So this conditional operator only works because we are basically giving it a dummy `return` value that we do not need because `void` is against the specifications.

Now you could always add a `return` that *means* something like

```
public static String passMarks(){
   passMark = marks;
   return "PASSED";
}
```

And use it like this:

```
String passed = (Grade > marks) ? passMarks() : failedMarks();
```

Which will set the values AND return the `String` that says `PASSED` or `FAILED`, and do multiple things at once!

**Note:**  I am pretending `passMark` and `marks` are class variables accessible from the method without passing it for ease of explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Assignments a = b in Java yield no value, but ternary operator expects some values to be returned out of it.

EDIT: I just realised that I don't resolve your issue.

Please note that that hacking the ternary operator with assignments taken into brackets is like kicking Java in the face.

Solution: You should NOT be assigning multiple variables in one line. Use multiple lines, as much as you need and then once the code is working and has no bugs you can try to make it more efficient.

A very important thing to understand in programming is that finding the smallest most convoluted solution to your problem may result in losing much time once you revisit it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like it (although not recommendable)

```
int marks;
int marks = (Grade > marks) ? (passMark = marks) : (failedMark = marks);
```

Because the ternary operator consists of a condition that evaluates to either true or false, plus a value that is returned if the condition is true and another value that is returned if the condition is false.

Comment: I will try this & test in Sonar

Comment: It is working as expected, but it is showing 2, 3 sonar issues like 'assigning variable should not be inside sub expression' etc.